# URI encoding problem

Tags: java

I am facing URI encoding problem with non-ascii chars like chinese and japanese.
if i am giving characters like "隐私权政策", it does not seems to make proper URI. any pointers will be helpful. here is a code snipp

```
String path ="c:\隐私权政策.txt";

File f = new File(path);

URI uri = f.toURI();

System.out.println(uri);

uri = new URI("file", null, uri.getPath(), null, null);

System.out.println(uri);
```

am I missing something here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does "it does not seems to make proper URI" mean?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your compiler is attempting to treat `\隐` as an escape character. It's not a valid escape, of course.

In fact, the backslash character isn't quite legal for a URI, per section 2.4.3 of [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

> Other characters are excluded because gateways and other transport
>      agents are known to sometimes modify such characters, or they are
>      used as delimiters.
>
> ```
> unwise      = "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"
> ```

However, some systems (e.g. [IIS](http://www.highdots.com/forums/html/rfc3986-backslash-uri-urls-178316.html)) convert backslashes into forward slashes silently.

I tried to run your code but ran into a number of errors that ultimately crashed MyEclipse, so this may not be the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Lord Torgamus is right. So, I switched the backslash for a forward slash. Surround statement with try and catch (suggested by netbeans), and then it worked.

```
try {
        uri = new URI("file", null, uri.getPath(), null, null);
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Console output:

```
run:
file:/c:/隐私权政策.txt
file:/c:/隐私权政策.txt
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: @Lord Torgamus and Roger , Thanks for the help. I just tried with the character 标题 and I am again getting some new characters in the URI, even using the backward slash. (I am getting %C2%A0 extra in this case) I checked out , the byte values , itself are wrong ones. any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the solution based on removing "/" or "\" or "file" by hand is not universal. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944586/715269) is the machine-independent solution